# Add style to ul inside li with Vue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a problem how to add style to ul inside clicked li with Vue JavaScript. My html code:

```
<ul>
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li @click="toggleSubMenu">Profile
      <ul> //Add class here
          <li>History</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li @click="toggleSubMenu">Media
      <ul :class="{ 'd-block' : data.sub_menu_show}">
          <li>Photos</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And my vue code:

```
<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup(){
        const data = reactive({
            sub_menu_show: '',
        });

        const toggleSubMenu = () => {
            data.sub_menu_show = !data.sub_menu_show
        }

        return{
            data,
            toggleSubMenu
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But, and my expectation is when toggleSubMenu clicked, the ul style added is only inside li that clicked, not add to all ul or other sub menu.

Thanks before.

Comment: `document.ul`? that's not how the DOM works ... you could do `document.querySelector('ul').style.cssText = 'display:block'` - though, that is equally naive as it infers that there's only one `ul` in the page

Comment: @JaromandaX i have update my question, i use :class="{ 'd-block' : data.sub_menu_show}" in <ul>. But the problem now is all the ul is added d-block class now

Comment: I was answering your question and all of a sudden the question changed and goes completely out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you are using a single state for multiple UI elements. How about this instead:

```html
<ul>
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li @click="() => toggleSubMenu('profile')">Profile
      <ul :class="{ 'd-block': toggleStates['profile'] }">
          <li>History</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li @click="() => toggleSubMenu('media')">Media
      <ul :class="{ 'd-block': toggleStates['media'] }">
          <li>Photos</li>
          <li>Videos</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

```js
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup(){
        const toggleStates = ref({ profile: false, media: false });

        const toggleSubMenu = (type) => {
            toggleStates.value[type] = !toggleStates.value[type];
        }

        return {
            toggleSubMenu,
            toggleStates
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank sir, but there is error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I forget to use `e.target.firstChild.classList.toggle('d-block');`. But anyway the target can be different if the click happens in inner elements. Let me find more stable solution for you.

Comment: thanks for your update sir, so if i have a new menu for it, i should add manually menu name in refs?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But if you want to build those menus and their content from some given/loaded data, you can also consider doing something similar using a generic list with "v-for" and iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

@click is a shorthand for writing v-on directive. This Vue directive by default passes an event argument that contains a lot of things including the target element to the specified callback function.

Therefore, apply the operation to that target element.

```
event.target.style.cssText = ''
```

Comment: thanks sir, but how to put the operation to target?